# Crashlytics Failing to Initialize

Tags: android, crashlytics, amazon-fire-tv

I am having trouble getting Crashlytics to work with the Amazon Fire TV. I have a project that targets Android, Android TV, and FireTV. Crashlytics seems to work just fine for Android and Android TV, but I'm getting an error when I run it, saying it timed out during initialization.

Here is the error:

```
04-16 12:30:11.051 6661-6661/com.acompany.app.firetvclient E/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics timed out during initialization.
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:176)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.finishInitSynchronously(CrashlyticsCore.java:727)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:298)
        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:211)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:466)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:410)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:368)
        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:339)
        at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:27)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5340)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4935)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4861)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:160)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1382)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5597)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:984)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Here is my build.gradle files for my project, and the firetv target:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.fabric.io/public"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.acompay.app.firetvclient"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 260
        versionName "2.6.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('assets/api_key.txt')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    implementation project(':bftools')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Do I need to set up Crashlytics differently for the Fire TV? I don't really understand why I'm getting that error.

Comment: Have you tried with `2.10.1`?